# Flutter passing images to iOS

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I am generating an image in Flutter and I have the image in bytes (defined as `imageInMemory` which is a UInt8List). I am then passing the bytes to the application.

```
UInt8List imageInMemory    

var argMap = <String, dynamic>{
          "image" : imageInMemory,
        };

    await platform.invokeMethod("passToNative", argMap);
```

How would I go about getting the arguments from the map and converting it to a UIImage on the Swift side of things?

Thanks in advance,
Jack

Answer (score 3):

On the Swift side in your methodChannel:

```
guard let arguments = call.arguments as? [String:FlutterStandardTypedData],
let data:FlutterStandardTypedData = arguments["image"] else {
    result("Couldn't find image data")
    return
}
let uiImage = UIImage(data: data.data)!
// do something with uiImage
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Dart side I encoded the image into a base64 String and passed it as argument to the Swift side. Then I converted the base64 String into a Data object which at the time is used to create the UIImage object.

```js
func uiImageFromData(base64: String) -> UIImage? {
    let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: base64, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!

    return UIImage(data: dataDecoded)
}
```